# Shogun: Which player resolves winter revolts first?

Tags: shogun

Given that several players are going to get revolts due to rice shortage in the winter round, which one goes first?

It might matter e.g. when you know that the tower is packed with green cubes and no one wants to go first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 10 of the rule book:

> If multiple players face revolts this winter, the revolts are resolved in the turn order of the preceding fall round.